# Selenium Webdriver - how to get the value in span tag

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<span id="email-display">myemailid</span>
```

How could i get the value between the span tag in selenium webdriver?
I tired using this code:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email-display']")).getText());
```

But i am not able to get the value. What has to be done? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: Is that element within a frame?

Comment: plz post the html source complete

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email-display']")).getAttribute("textContent")
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span#email-display")).getText());
```

if this can not get text, please paste html with parent root and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("email-display")).getText();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='email-display']")).getText();
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span#email-display")).getText();
```

If that element is in new window or in frame, then switch to that window / frame, then perform the operations.